# Is there a way to prevent auto-exit from Lucioball?

Tags: overwatch

After each game of Lucioball, Overwatch auto-exits to the main menu. Is there a way to set it to automatically stay in the queue for another game?

I'm not sure if this applies to other brawls, since I've never played one before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucioball is a brawl. The brawl always exits after the game ends. There is no way to auto-queue for a new brawl.